# How to redirect to a particular controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in my rake routes:

```
{:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"mobile/home"}
                                                              mobile_disclosures GET    /disclosures(.:format)                                                                                                     {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"index", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                                                 POST   /disclosures(.:format)                                                                                                     {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"create", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                           new_mobile_disclosure GET    /disclosures/new(.:format)                                                                                                 {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"new", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                          edit_mobile_disclosure GET    /disclosures/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                                            {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                               mobile_disclosure GET    /disclosures/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"show", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                                                 PUT    /disclosures/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"update", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}
                                                                                 DELETE /disclosures/:id(.:format)
```

and I am trying to redirect my controller to: `mobile_disclosures`

by trying something like this:

```
  redirect_to :controller=>'mobile_disclosures', :action => 'show'
```

But I am getting an error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"mobile/mobile_disclosures", :action=>"show"}

Any idea what is wrong with my syntax and where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show requires an ID so you will need to pass in the ID as well.

```
redirect_to :controller=>'mobile_disclosures', :action => 'show', :id => some_id
```

Comment: yeah but even doing action => 'index' gives the error: No route matches {:controller=>"mobile/mobile_disclosures"}

Comment: try doing something like: redirect_to mobile_disclosure_url(some_id)

Comment: Btw, what should be some_id - I dont think I have an id to pass.  I think redirecting to the index controller is actually what I should be doing.

Comment: cool, got it.  This is what worked for me: redirect_to mobile_disclosures_url , :action => 'index'